# Как правильно написать SQL запрос с использованием переменной

Tags: sql-server

Задача: разделить данные за сегодня и вчера по столбцам.
Если использовать этот запрос без переменных то все работает.
Анализ синтаксиса ругает на Declare @today...
Используется MSSQL 2016

```
    Declare @today, @yesterday as Date;
Set @today = GETDATE(), @yesterday = GetDate()-2;
SELECT CAST(o.CreatedDate AS DATE), n.CategoryName,
SUM(CASE WHEN o.Status =  'N' And  o.CreatedDate = @today Then i.ReservePrice * i.Quantity END)  as NewSum,
SUM(CASE WHEN o.Status =  'N' And  o.CreatedDate = @today Then 1 END)  as NewQuantity,
SUM(CASE WHEN o.Status =  'W' And  o.CreatedDate = @today Then i.ReservePrice * i.Quantity END) as WaitingSum,
SUM(CASE WHEN o.Status =  'W' And  o.CreatedDate = @today Then 1 END) as WaitingQuantity,
SUM(CASE WHEN o.Status =  'U' And  o.CreatedDate = @today Then i.ReservePrice * i.Quantity END)  as ProblemSum,
SUM(CASE WHEN o.Status =  'U' And  o.CreatedDate = @today Then 1 END)  as ProblemQuantity,
SUM(CASE WHEN o.Status =  'Z' And  o.CreatedDate = @today Then i.ReservePrice * i.Quantity END)  as CancelledSum,
SUM(CASE WHEN o.Status =  'Z' And  o.CreatedDate = @today Then 1 END)  as CancelledQuantity,
SUM(CASE WHEN o.Status =  'N' And  o.CreatedDate = @yesterday Then i.ReservePrice * i.Quantity END)  as yesterdayNewSum,
SUM(CASE WHEN o.Status =  'N' And  o.CreatedDate = @yesterday Then 1 END)  as yesterdayNewQuantity,
SUM(CASE WHEN o.Status =  'W' And  o.CreatedDate = @yesterday Then i.ReservePrice * i.Quantity END) as yesterdayWaitingSum,
SUM(CASE WHEN o.Status =  'W' And  o.CreatedDate = @yesterday Then 1 END) as yesterdayWaitingQuantity,
SUM(CASE WHEN o.Status =  'U' And  o.CreatedDate = @yesterday Then i.ReservePrice * i.Quantity END)  as yesterdayProblemSum,
SUM(CASE WHEN o.Status =  'U' And  o.CreatedDate = @yesterday Then 1 END)  as yesterdayProblemQuantity,
SUM(CASE WHEN o.Status =  'Z' And  o.CreatedDate = @yesterday Then i.ReservePrice * i.Quantity END)  as yesterdayCancelledSum,
SUM(CASE WHEN o.Status =  'Z' And  o.CreatedDate = @yesterday Then 1 END)  as yesterdayCancelledQuantity


FROM Orders o 
LEFT JOIN OrderItems i ON i.OrderID = o.ID
LEFT JOIN NomenclUS n ON n.ID = i.ProductID

WHERE i.Status <> 'Z' AND o.CreatedDate >= dateadd(day, -2, getdate())

GROUP BY n.CategoryID, n.CategoryName
ORDER BY n.CategoryID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DECLARE @today as Date, @yesterday as Date;`
Вы не указали тип для первой переменной, допускается объявление несольких переменных в одном блоке DECLARE, но тип опускать нельзя.

Подробнее: [DECLARE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: Спасибо. А set нельзя через ","? У меня начал на него ругаться

Comment: @WebAnalytics SET тоже только одной переменной присвоит значение, вам поможет `SELECT @today = GETDATE(), @yesterday = GetDate()-2;`